# Canonical transformations to quotient spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, $U_1, U_2 \subset V$ vector subspaces of a $K$-vector space. Considering the following canonical $K$-linear transformations:

$$p_1: V \rightarrow V/U_1$$
$$p_2: V \rightarrow V/U_2$$

Show that

$$p_1 \times p_2: V\rightarrow V/U_1 \oplus V/U_2$$ $$v\longmapsto (p_1(v),p_2(v))$$

is a K-linear transformation and calculate the nullspace $ker(p_1 \times p_2)$.

First of all, what are the canonical $K$-linear transformations? Are there explicit expressions?

The proof that they are $K$-linear:

Let $u, v \in V$.

$(p_1 \times p_2) (u+v)=(p_1(u+v), p_2(u+v))=(p_1(u)+p_1(v), p_2(u)+p_2(v))=(p_1(u),p_2(u))+(p_1(v), p_2(v))=(p_1 \times p_2) (u)+(p_1 \times p_2) (v)$

Let $ v \in V,\alpha \in K$.

$(p_1 \times p_2) (\alpha v)=(p_1(\alpha v), p_2(\alpha v))=(\alpha  p_1( v), \alpha p_2( v)))=\alpha ((p_1 \times p_2) (v)) $

Is this correct? I am not sure since I do not know the expressions for $p_1, p_2$.

Also for the nullspace $ker(p_1 \times p_2)$ I have deducted that $ker(p_1 \times p_2)$=$ker(p_1) \cap ker(p_2)$.

Is there anything more precise to say about $ker(p_1 \times p_2)$? This is where I am not sure at all.

Thanks for help.